# relearning PHP, how has it changed?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm planning on creating a small web app using PHP. The last time I used PHP was sometime around 2002/2003 where the code tended to be a horrid mash of PHP/HTML and Javascript shoved in a single file. I think I might have even been using PHP3...

I now want to relearn and want to know what's changed and what helper libraries and tooklits exist that might save me from unknowingly reinventing things.

E.g is there a "standard" MySQL library, or do we still use the basic PHP functions (as a side question, do stored procedures work in MySQL yet?)? What do I need to know in order to make a "modern" website that doesn't rely on whole page HTML form posts to send data back to the server, etc.

Comment: i recommend looking at some of the OOP improvements of php5 and maybe take a look at some newer frameworks (as zend framework)

Comment: programming languages evolve, not change. The approach towards development change (eg: MVC for web apps).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Welcome back. PHP has gotten better!

If you can, start using 5.3 from the start; be aware though that many web hosts don't support it yet (if that is an issue). If confronted with PHP 4, run away screaming: It is no longer fit for production use.

- The major development is [finally proper OOP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) in PHP 5. Getting familiar with that is the only really mandatory thing in my eyes.
- [Several popular  frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648/what-php-framework-would-you-choose-for-a-new-application-and-why) have evolved that do a lot of low-level work for you. The [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) is a very high-quality code base to work with and my personal favourite because it's also usable as a component library that doesn't force its design principles upon you; there are others. ([Here](http://www.phpframeworks.com/) is a comparison site).
- [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) is definitely the low-level database class *de jour.* It has parametrized queries preventing SQL injection and supports [a number of databases](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php).
- The [MVC design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Controller) is a very popular design pattern for building dynamic web sites and applications, and is embedded as a design philosophy into most PHP frameworks.
- [Class Autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) is a great new PHP 5 feature.
- A relatively little-noticed new development is the [Standard PHP Library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php) that brings clean, OOP solutions to everyday PHP problems. For example the [DirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) that allows for easy recursive walking through directories; the [ArrayObject](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) provides an OOP interface to many (but not all) core array functions.
- The [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) will replace the old UNIX timestamps over time. It provides improved functionality, and can work with dates beyond the 32 bit timestamp's 1970-2038 range.

This is some of the stuff under the hood. There are important client-side developments you want to be at least aware of; namely [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) to fetch server-side data without reloading the page, and using a JavaScript Framework like [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) to deal with the details. CSS you will already be  familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

Move to Zend framework when you start , first do some good research on OOP. Make sure you are understanding well terms as polymorphizm and inheritance. The last thing you must learn are php patterns like singletone pattern and factory pattern , abstract classes and interface implementation.

Comment: "The last thing you must learn are php patterns like singletone pattern and factory pattern" - PHP patterns!? Seriously!?

Comment: There may be a language problem here. When a native English speaker says "The last thing you must [do] is ... ", this idiom often means "Do not do this!", but I don't think that that is what Max intended. I don't understand jondro's comment so I don't know for sure, but I think they may have taken Max's statement the other way.

Comment: I'm not sure what is all about lol :)  Just a few tips what to learn .

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough. Singleton and factory are DESIGN patterns that apply to all object oriented languages. They are NOT php patterns.

Comment: That's true , you can use those on any language and php support those techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Here are solutions:

1. Use [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software) to abstract from SQL >> E.g is there a "standard" MySQL library, or do we still use the basic PHP functions
2. Use [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller#PHP) framework  >>  helper libraries and tooklits exist
3. Use Javascript for better user experience [JS Frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ajax_frameworks#JavaScript) >> make a "modern" website